# decimal point conversion issue in distance calculation using latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, coordinates, distance

I'm encountering an issue with calculating distances based on latitude and longitude coordinates. I'm retrieving the current coordinates using a JavaScript function, which then writes these values into two hidden fields on the page. In the code-behind, I'm passing these values along with fixed coordinates to a function to calculate the distance. However, the calculated distance seems to be in thousands of kilometers, even when checking the same latitude and longitude values.

Here's the JavaScript code snippet responsible for obtaining the coordinates on the aspx page:

```
var lat = position.coords.latitude;
var lng = position.coords.longitude;
document.getElementById('<%=latitudine.ClientID %>').value = lat;
document.getElementById('<%=longitudine.ClientID %>').value = lng;
```

Then in code behind I have this function

```
Public Function gpsCordDistance(ByVal pointLat As Double, ByVal pointLon As Double, ByVal locLat As Double, ByVal locLon As Double) As Double
        Dim R As Double = 6371
        Dim dLat As Double = deg2rad(pointLat - locLat)
        Dim dLon As Double = deg2rad(pointLon - locLon)
        Dim lat1 As Double = deg2rad(locLat)
        Dim lat2 As Double = deg2rad(pointLat)
        Dim a As Double = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) + Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2)
        Dim c As Double = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a))
        Dim d As Double = R * c
        Return d
    End Function
```

to which I'm passing values like this:

```
Dim getLat As String = latitudine.Value
Dim getLon As String = longitudine.Value
gpsCordDistance(44.4040527, 8.9336762, getLat, getLon)
```

While the fixed values I'm passing to the function are dotted (44.4040527, 8.9336762) I see when I debug the code that getLat e getLon are managed differently, whitout the dot like 444040527, 89336762. I guess it is a type conversion problem but I can't figure out how to solve it. Any help please?

Comment: Your `gpsCordDistance` is expecting double values, you're passing strings. `Dim getLat As Double = Double.Parse(latitudine.Value) etc.`. Consider the `TryParse()` variant to validate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used

```
Dim getLat As Double = CDbl(Val(latitudine.Value))
Dim getLon As Double = CDbl(Val(longitudine.Value))
```

and seems to do the trick